Is it safe and ok to divide mp3 file like that?
I have an mp3 file and want to divide it into several files ("chunks"). I came up with this code (I stole the idea from django):
from pathlib import Path


class FileWrapper:
    def __init__(self, file) -> None:
        self.file = file

    def chunks(self, chunk_size):
        chunk_size = chunk_size
        try:
            self.file.seek(0)
        except (AttributeError, Exception):
            pass

        while True:
            data = self.file.read(chunk_size)
            if not data:
                break
            yield data


with open("./test.mp3", "rb+") as src:
    wrapper_file = FileWrapper(src)
    for chunk_ind, chunk in enumerate(wrapper_file.chunks(chunk_size=100 * 1024)):
        out_file_path = Path("./", f"test_{chunk_ind}.mp3")
        with open(out_file_path, "wb+") as destination:
            destination.write(chunk)


And, you know, it's working okay, I can play resulted "chunks", but I'm scary and in doubt, that this approach can sometimes work, but sometimes it maybe can "brake" resulted "chunks". So, is this way - okay? Or I need to dive deeper into how mp3 files made?

The line except (AttributeError, Exception) scares me a bit.

Just because software X is able to "play" the resulting files doesn't mean they're undamaged or respect a format - software Y may fail at them, not to speak of informing you at all about issues. Due to MPEG's nature players most likely just sync for the next frame they find, ingnoring anything before as unknown potential metadata. So no: it's not safe to do it like that.

Technically, your method of reading an MP3 file in chunks and dividing it could work, but it might produce audio portions that are damaged or insufficient. Certain structures, such as frames and headers, are encoded in MP3 files and must be observed while slicing them. The integrity of the audio might be compromised by simply splitting an MP3 into byte-sized pieces, which could result in problems like halving a frame.
Using the pydub library, which is made for working with audio files at a higher level and takes care of the encoding specifics for you, is a more dependable method of splitting MP3 files.

In addition to frames, it's also worth mentioning the bit reservoir, where decoding the audio often depends on data from other frames.

Also ID3v2.4 tags might appear anywhere inbetween the file (§ 4.29 SEEK frame) and you might cut them.
